# Red plot background for negative sign

Tags: plotting, color

In the following `Plot`

```
f[x_]:= Sin[2*Pi*x]   
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2}]
```

I want to add red `Background` color where `f[x]` is negative (so that it automatically works for any `f[x]`)  but have not yet found out how.

I need something like  [image]

Particulary I want to use it for `f[x]` whose roots are difficult to find analytically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with the `Filling` option. Change `Green` to `Opacity[0]` if you don't want it.

```
f[x_] := Sin[2*Pi*x]
Plot[{f[x], 0}, {x, 0, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Red, Green}}}]
```

[image: filling example]

Edit: to achieve what you want in your edit you can use a `Sign` function:

```
f[x_] := Sin[2*Pi*x]
Plot[{Sign[-f[x]], f[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> Bottom}, 
 FillingStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> {{Opacity[0]}, {Thick, Black}}]
```

[image: filling example 2 with Sign]

Also, if you do this with a function and min/max is outside of {-1,1} then you'll need to scale the `Sign` up and limit the plot range because otherwise you'd have it capped off at +1 and a ridge at -1.

```
f[x_] := 6 E^-x Sin[2*Pi*x^2]
Plot[{1000 Sign[-f[x]], f[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, Filling -> {1 -> Bottom}, 
 FillingStyle -> Red, PlotStyle -> {{Opacity[0]}, {Thick, Black}}, 
 PlotRange -> {-5, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: How can I modify this to get all of the background in red where `f[x]` is negative?

Comment: I've updated my answer. The Filling is applied to the Sign function only and I've hidden its curve using Opacity[0].

Answer (score 4):

```
Plot[{f[x], ConditionalExpression[0, f[x] < 0]}, {x, 0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, None}, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {Bottom, Red}, 2 -> {Top, Red}}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{f[x], f[x], ConditionalExpression[0, f[x] < 0]}, {x, 0, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], White], Black, None}, 
 Filling -> {3 -> {Bottom, Red}, 3 -> {Top, Red}}]
```

[image]

```
f2[x_] := x Sin[x Cos[3 x ]]

Plot[{f2[x], ConditionalExpression[0, f2[x] < 0]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, None}, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 Filling -> {2 -> {Bottom, Red}, 2 -> {Top, Red}}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{f2[x], f2[x], ConditionalExpression[0, f2[x] < 0]}, {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], White], Black,  None}, 
  Filling -> {3 -> {Bottom, Red}, 3 -> {Top, Red}},  PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general, but *slow* method, which uses `DensityPlot[]` to generate the shading. To make things more interesting, I'll use a different function:

```
f[x_] := Exp[(x - 5)/10] BesselJ[0, x] (BesselJZero[0, 3] - x) (x - BesselJZero[0, 4])/20

{xmin, xmax} = {0, 25};
pl = Plot[f[x], {x, xmin, xmax}];
{ymin, ymax} = Last[Charting`get2DPlotRange[pl]];
shade = Cases[DensityPlot[Sign[f[x]], {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
                          ColorFunction -> (RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 0.8 (1 - #)] &)],
              _GraphicsComplex, ∞];

Show[pl, Prolog -> shade]
```

[image: shaded plot 1]

As you can see, it works even if the function does not exhibit sign changes at its zeroes.

---

Because that method can be slow, I will also present a less-general procedure, which is only useful if the function is continuous, and all of the its zeroes are of odd multiplicity.

This uses a combination of the `MeshFunctions` option of `Plot[]` to locate zeroes, and `Rectangle[]` + `Scaled[]` to generate the shading. I will again use a different function for the purpose:

```
f[x_] := AiryAi[x]

pl = Plot[f[x], {x, -14, 2}, Mesh -> {{0}},
          MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, MeshStyle -> Automatic];

np = First[Normal[pl]];
rts = Sort[Cases[np, Point[{x_, _}] :> x, ∞]];
lin = Flatten[Cases[np, Line[l_] :> l, ∞], 1];

{x0, f0} = First[MinimalBy[lin, First]];
{x1, f1} = First[MaximalBy[lin, First]];

sgn = Join[{Sign[f0]}, Sign[f'[rts]], {Sign[f1]}];
rts = Join[{x0}, rts, {x1}];

shade = Apply[Rectangle,
              MapThread[Scaled, {{{0, -1}, {0, 1}},
                                 Transpose[{rts[[#]], {0, 0}}]}]] & /@
        SequencePosition[sgn, {-1, 1}];

Graphics[{{Opacity[2/3, Red], shade}, DeleteCases[np, _Point, ∞]},
         AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Axes -> True, PlotRange -> PlotRange[pl]]
```

[image: shaded plot 2]